# Laptop screen goes black for a few seconds when I turn on my microphone

Tags: laptop, display, microphone

I am using an [Asus TUF FX504GD](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-TUF-Gaming-FX504/) laptop, and I encounter a problem where my laptop screen would go black for a few seconds (the screen may or may not come back on after it goes black) when I turn on my microphone. It happened in game while I talked via Discord, and even in browser, when I record voice messages on Whatsapp Web, for example.

It does not happen every single time I turn on my mic. But whenever it happened, it was at the moment my mic was turned on. I tried updating audio and display driver, but the problem still persists. The laptop screen was replaced, but still same.

Does anyone encounter same issue and have an idea how to solve it?

Comment: try to check if your power supply is properly earthed. I once had a broken power extension cord which caused a similar problem

Comment: I encountered the problem with my laptop even when it was not plugged in.

Comment: this may be the discord overlay (if enabled) causing a problem with your graphic drivers.