# Windows machine excessively flickers for a few seconds when connecting >= 2 displays

Tags: windows, display, multiple-monitors

One of my desktops flickers excessively when it has more than one display connected:

[image: Video gif]

When I connect one display, there's a brief sub-second flicker that's bearable, but any more than that and I get the excessive, multi-second flickering. It doesn't matter which display I connect second, and happens with additional displays (e.g. several VR headsets) if used in lieu of or in addition to the second monitor.

Device 1 (with flicker):

- Windows 11 22000.795 (21H2)
- NVIDIA RTX 2080 TI (driver version 516.59)
- Monitors @ 1440p, 144Hz
- [Detailed DxDiag Information](https://pastebin.com/raw/U84jJKfk)

However, when I use the same exact monitors at the same exact refresh rate/resolution with the same cables on a different device, the flickering does not happen. (I had to use a HDMI->DP adapter on Device 2 since it only has a single DP port, but even if I use HDMI+the adapter on Device 1 there is no change)

Device 2 (never flickers):

- Windows 10
- NVIDIA RTX 2060
- Monitors @ 1440p, 144Hz
- [Detailed DxDiag Information](https://pastebin.com/raw/hc4b7dCF)

The GPUs are the same generation, so I would be surprised if there were a major discrepancy between the 2060 and 2080 TI that led to the issue. I don't think it's an issue with the GPU's driver either because this has been happening for some time, spanning many driver versions. The biggest suspect I have is Windows 11, but my KVM manufacturer (who I originally thought was at fault before removing the KVM from the equation and finding it still happens) says they test/develop on Windows 11 and don't see this issue. Past that, I'd suspect maybe the VR devices I've used exclusively on Device 1 (which were completely disconnected for the video above) have installed some bad driver or something, but it's weird that it'd interfere without them connected.

I've seen similar questions where [a program overlay was causing issues](https://superuser.com/q/1546421/413648), but this happens even when I close as many open applications, overlay or not, that I can. There are also a lot of questions where this flickering persists permanently, but that's not what's happening here -- rather than some bad cable, device, or similar that's distorting the signal, it seems in this case that the display is disconnecting/reconnecting rapidly, and does not have any distortion while connected.

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: What happens if you shut the machine down, connect the displays firmly, and start it up again?  Same flicker?

Comment: No, this does not happen on reboot. Only after POST. However, when rebooting this time, I found the root issue: the VR headsets (specifically the HP Reverb G2). The previous times I rebooted, I had the headset connected. It seems it does something to the system once connected that triggers this issue even once the headset is fully disconnected. This time though I had it disconnected from the prior tests. Reboot the system and never connect the headsets? Issue never happens. Mystery solved!

Answer (score 0):

flickering is part of the DP continuity test for the link.

Has to do with the Monitor, the Port or the cable.